# Show that $|a-b|\le 1/n \Longrightarrow a=b$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $a,b\in \Bbb R$. Show that if $|a-b|\le\frac{1}{n}$ for every $n\in \Bbb N$ then $a=b$.

I tried writing $n$ in function of $(a,b)$ but a natural number can't be written in function of two real number !

Comment: @Tintarn see the edit

Comment: Prove the convergence of 1/n and n approaches infinity. Then by that you can show that |a-b| converges to 0.

Comment: @user60887: How can the **number** $|a-b|$ converge to anything?

Comment: Fix epsilon. since $|a-b|<\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$, it follows that if we fix $\epsilon>0$, then by the archimdean principle there exists a $n_\epsilon>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ such that $\frac{1}{n_\epsilon}<\epsilon$ then $||a-b|-0|<\frac{1}{n_\epsilon}<\epsilon$. Hence |a-b|=0.

Comment: @user60887: Yes, I agree that $|a-b|$ is (nonnegative and) less than every positive number, and so must be $0$. But $|a-b|$ *is a number*, not a sequence, so it makes no sense to say that it "converges" to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a\ne b,$ then $0<|a-b|\le\frac1n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N.$ Thus, $$n\le\frac1{|a-b|}$$ for all $n\in\Bbb N,$ meaning that $\frac1{|a-b|}$ is a real upper bound of $\Bbb N.$ But this is impossible. (Why?)

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is a given number then the proposition is false so I assume the question means "for all $n$".

Now by symmetry we assume $a>b$ and let $c=a-b>0$. Then we have $c < {1\over n}$ for all $n$. Let $d={1\over c}$ then $d>n$ for all $n$, which implies $d+2>n$ for all $n$, contradicting there must be a natural number between $d$ and $d+2$.

Comment: How did you add 2 to d without adding it to n ?

Comment: @user233658: By transitivity of order, since $d>n$ and $d+2>d,$ then $d+2>n$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a \neq b$, then $|a-b| > 0$ and there is a special $n_0$ such that $\frac{1}{n_0} < |a-b|$, by the Archimedian property of $\Bbb R$. But the hypothesis says $|a-b| \leq \frac{1}{n_0}$, and so $\frac{1}{n_0} < \frac{1}{n_0}$, a contradiction.